# Separation of variables and Fourier transformation

Tags: brownian-motion, heat-equation

I know there's another question very similar to this argument. In the book *Probabilità e Modelli Aleatori* of Enzo Orsingher, at page 134, it shows that the transition function of an absorbing Brownian Motion is the solution of the following problem:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{d^2u}{2dx^2} &  x < a,t>0 \\
u(t_0,x,t_0,x_0)=\delta(x-x_0) \\
u(t,a,t_0,x_0)=0\\
\lim_{x \to -\infty} u(t,x,t_0,x_0)=0 & \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{du}{dx}(t,x,t_0,x_0)=0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
To solve this problem, the books uses the separation of variables and rewrites the solution of the heat equation in this way:
$$u(t,x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\beta^2t} \{A(\beta)e^{i\beta x}+B(\beta)e^{-i\beta x}\}$$
I really don't understand how to obtain this form. I looked a lot on the web for an answer but I didn't find it. Every time I look for the separation of variables in the heat equation, the result has a different form.

Comment: The separation of variables you're probably used to (or finding online) is for PDEs defined on a finite spatial region (e.g. $0 < x < L < \infty$). In that case, the key differential operator ($\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}$) has a countable spectrum (a countable number of eigenvalues), and so the solution is written as a sum. 

In this case, the spatial region is unbounded, and so the Fourier transform is the appropriate tool. I'm going to decline writing out a full solution (because it's not immediately clear to me how to reach the given solution), but that should get you started.

Comment: thanks a lot for the comment, now I understand why the use of the Fourier transfrom instead of the sum.